# Foreign keys not "working"?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a system for a newspaper for a school project, and this is part of that code. For some reason i am getting "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint"

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema nyheterhiof
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema nyheterhiof
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS nyheterhiof DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE nyheterhiof ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table nyheterhiof.newspapers
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nyheterhiof.newspapers (
  newspaper_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  newspaper_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  newspaper_city VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (newspaper_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX newspaper_id_UNIQUE (newspaper_id ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table nyheterhiof.newspaper_Issues
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nyheterhiof.newspaper_issues (
  newspaper_issiue_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  newspaper_id VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  publication_date DATE NOT NULL,
  comment VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (newspaper_issiue_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX newspaper_issiue_id_UNIQUE (newspaper_issiue_id ASC),
  INDEX fk_newspaper_Issues_newspapers1_idx (newspaper_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_newspaper_Issues_newspapers1
    FOREIGN KEY (newspaper_id)
    REFERENCES newspapers (newspaper_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I have tried moving the FK to a alter table statment, I have tried adding indexes to newspaper_id in "newspaper_issiues".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nyheterhiof.newspapers (
  newspaper_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nyheterhiof.newspaper_issues (
  ...
  newspaper_id VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
```

This is the problem. The columns at both ends of a foreign key constraint ***MUST*** match in type and width.

Redefine `newspaper_issues.newspaper_id` as **`INT`** and you'll be good to go.